# Cliente GIT é possivel acessar servidor compartilhado ou fazer push automatico

Tags: git

Boa noite a todos;

Recentemente configurei um servidor git com diversos projetos para que os desenvolvedores consigam trabalhar em um único servidor GIT, porem quando é usado o cliente git o desenvolvedor precisa fazer um clone do projeto do servidor git compartilhado do projeto correspondente e quando é feito o push de alterações etc isso vai para o servidor GIT, existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o push do cliente GIT faça as alterações necessárias e o servidor GIT faça o push 'upload das alterações' para  servidores cliente em produção onde estaio efetivamente as aplicações ? ou um cliente no qual as conexões são feitas parecido co FTP para que possa trabalhar remoto no servidor, o cenário seria parecido da seguinte maneira.

cliente push > projeto servidor GIT compartilhado > push automático para servidor clientes de produção.

Obrigado.

Comment: Apesar de não estar muito claro sua dúvida, acredito que seja algo assim que deseje, https://jenkins.io/

Comment: O que você provavelmente quer é criar um job automatizado de build e deploy usando uma ferramenta chamada Jenkins. Com ela, você consegue que, por exemplo, um commit do Git sensibilize uma série de tarefas realizadas em sequência (pipeline), como o upload que você quer. Dê uma pesquisada a respeito, tem bastante coisa na internet.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde

Configurei a integração continua com o Jenkins e a função que preciso esta funcionando corretamente GIT e Jenkins.

Obrigado